# Expandible TextInput to maximum number of lines in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am trying to make a TextInput where the user can input texts up to a maximum of say four lines. The user can continue inputting text as the textinput now auto scrolls.

```
const InputNoLabel = ({ value, onChangeText, placeholder, 
secureTextEntry, onContentSizeChange, height }) => {
const { inputStyle, containerStyle } = styles;
 return (
  <View style={containerStyle}>
  <TextInput
    underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
    secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
    placeholder={placeholder}
    autoCorrect={false}
    style={[inputStyle, { height }]} //height: height
    value={value}
    onChangeText={onChangeText}
    onContentSizeChange={onContentSizeChange}
    multiline={true}
    editable={true}
  />
 </View>
 );
};
```

onContentSizeChange I manually change the height of my container passing a new height but when I reach my maximum height, any more text I type is simply hidden.

```
 <View style={rowContainer}>
     <InputNoLabel 
     label="Enter Text Here"
     placeholder="Name"
     onChangeText={this.onTextChange.bind(this)}
      /* value={this.state.value} */
      height={this.state.height}
      onContentSizeChange={this.onContentSizeChange.bind(this)}
     />
  </View >

 onContentSizeChange() {
    this.setState({
         height: Math.max(48, this.state.height + 16) 
     });
 }
```

How do I get the TextInput to resize to a maximum number of lines for input but also but also allow for more input but this time round only scrolling the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I have realised that this is a challenge of react on the Android side. 
I picked up component that can auto-scroll on android. 
You can clone the component here 
[MultilineTextInput](https://gist.github.com/codewithpassion/d2d1a3e4d94c547e6b343ea5e9fe9845).
Do some more styling to the textInput as you may wish.

Comment: The react team solved the problem, now you can use `TextInput` pass it `numberOfLines` you want as a prop, pass it `BlurOnSubmit` as false and `Multiline` as true

Answer (score 7):

I see this question has been around a while ago but it doesn't actually have a good answer, this is a simple workaround that you can use!

```js
<TextInput
  multiline
  style={{ maxHeight: 200 }} // => The Magic
/>
```

Check this simple snack I made: [snack.expo.io/@abranhe/stackoverflow-46851975](https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/stackoverflow-46851975)

[image]

The code... ?

```js
import React from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, TextInput as Input } from 'react-native';

export default () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Input
      autoFocus
      multiline
      style={styles.input}
      placeholder={'Enter your text!'}
    />
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    paddingTop: 100,
  },
  input: {
    borderRadius: 20,
    minHeight: 40,
    maxHeight: 200,
    margin: 20,
    padding: 20,
    borderWidth: 1,
  },
});
```

If you want to create something like a messaging app you can use this package [github.com/ardaogulcan/react-native-keyboard-accessory](https://github.com/ardaogulcan/react-native-keyboard-accessory)  and reuse the input.

Check the demo: [snack.expo.io/@abranhe/input-keyword-accessory](https://snack.expo.io/@abranhe/input-keyword-accessory)

[image]

Source code:

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { KeyboardAccessoryView } from 'react-native-keyboard-accessory';
import { View, Button, TextInput, StyleSheet, ScrollView } from 'react-native';

export default () => {
  const [focus, setFocus] = useState(false);

  const renderInput = () => (
    <KeyboardAccessoryView alwaysVisible>
      <TextInput
        onBlur={() => setFocus(false)}
        autoFocus
        multiline
        style={styles.input}
        placeholder={'Enter your text!'}
      />
    </KeyboardAccessoryView>
  );

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <ScrollView>
        <Button title="Send a message" onPress={() => setFocus(true)} />
      </ScrollView>
      {focus ? renderInput() : <View />}
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'flex-start',
    paddingTop: 30,
  },
  input: {
    margin: 5,
    minHeight: 40,
    maxHeight: 100,
  },
});
```

Comment: Great! Solved my issue!

Answer (score 2):

I have very easy solution with less code and cross-platform approach.

```
<View style={{ maxHeight: 100 }}> // 100 is sufficient for me
  <TextInput
     placeholder="Enter here"
     multiline={true}
     textAlignVertical="top"
  />
</View>
```

Expo [live demo here](https://snack.expo.io/@raajnadar/max-number-of-lines-for-textinput)

Comment: Good Approach ....

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I have to limit to `numberOfLines={4}` and this was my solution

```
const [heightOnChange, setHeightOnChange] = useState(60);
//min height >>>> 60

<View style={{height: heightOnChange}}>
   <TextInput
      multiline={true}
      numberOfLines={4}
      onContentSizeChange={e => {
         if (e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height < 90) {
            setHeightOnChange(e.nativeEvent.contentSize.height + 20);
            //20 for padding
         }
      }}
   />
</View>
```

I think this will be helpful for someone

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextInput maxLength = {5000}
                onChangeText={setInMessageText}
                placeholder={`Write a message`}
                value={inMessageText}
                multiline={true} //here
                style={{maxHeight: 100}}  //and here
              />
```